# Как центрировать кнопки в BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

Обновил implementaion для navigation в своем проекте, кнопки в нижнем меню растянулись по всей ширине. Как вернуть, чтобы было по середине?

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_items_color"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_items_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите скрины, до и после а то не понятно в чем дело

Comment: Добавил то, как выглядит после обновления. До, к сожалению, нет возможности вернуть, поэтому сюда и написал

Comment: А еще, теперь, почему то, при нажатии на эти кнопки, эффект нажатия растягивается серым цветом в прямоугольной форме по всему размеру кнопки, а не как раньше, красиво, кругло. Фото приложил, что имел ввиду